# Line-Height VS Padding in Nav (Correct Method)

Tags: html, padding, css

I am just getting back into coding and I would like to know what is the best method for adding heigh to my btn.

Here is the code -

Padding method

```
.nav-main li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 70px 10px 70px 10px;
  color: #6CF784;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Line-height method

```
.nav-main li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: #6CF784;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I personally use padding as it gives me more control across browsers, as line height can vary on which font you are using, along with what fonts are installed/not installed on the clients' browser.

Answer (score 18):

I like to use `line-height` because it positions the baseline correctly to make the text appear in the middle of the element (whereas with padding it may be off-centre one way or the other based on the font)

Of course, this relies on you using a pixel value for `line-height` (as you are doing in your question) - using a numeric value like `1.5` may produce different results depending on the font.

Answer (score 0):

```
.link {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: aqua;
   border: 2px solid aqua;
   margin: 30px auto;
   display: block;
   width: 160px;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 35px;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.link::before {
   content: attr(data-text);
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   transform: translateX(-100%);
   transition: 0.5s;
}
```

You will show the difference between the padding and line height
when you use pseudo element (before and aftere) =>
with line height the pseudo element take the same height of his parent
with padding the pseudo element do not take the height of his parent