# Increase padding just for one list in quarto/revealjs presentation

Tags: html, css, quarto, reveal.js

I just started learning how to use `quarto`/`revealjs` to prepare presentations and I was wondering how I can define a `.css` file to modify the padding between list elements, but only for one list (instead of the complete `qmd` document).

For example, I know that if I consider the following CSS text

```css
.reveal li {
  padding: 25px; 
}
```

save it in a `style.css` file, and include it in the following `qmd` document

```r
---
format: 
  revealjs: 
    css: style.css
---

## Bullets

Increase padding for the elements of this list

- A
- B

but not for this list

- C
- D
```

then I can increase the spacing between the list items for the whole document:

[image: output of previous code chunk]

However, I would like to modify just one list. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create an `extrapad` class, setting `margin-bottom` for each list item except the last. We can add the [`!important`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) override to ensure that it applies rather than the default `reveal.js` CSS list rule.

```r
.extrapad li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom:60px  !important;
}
```

Then use the Pandoc [fenced div notation](https://pandoc.org/chunkedhtml-demo/8.18-divs-and-spans.html) to apply this to the relevant list in your qmd file:

```
---
format: 
  revealjs: 
    css: styles.css
---

## Bullets

Increase padding for the elements of this list

:::{.extrapad}
- A 
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, class maecenas eros dictum enim pharetra curabitur, sed sed. Morbi et, accumsan
- B
:::

but not for this list

- C
- D
```

Output:

[image]

`margin-bottom` applies to space between elements in the list, unlike `line-height` which would also create space between lines.

See also:

- [Add space between <li> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903773/add-space-between-li-elements)
- [Line-Height VS Padding in Nav (Correct Method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551551/line-height-vs-padding-in-nav-correct-method)

Comment: Thank you very much! I only noticed that if the text included in the bullet points covers multiple lines, then line-height = 75px also increases the spacing between the different lines, however I would like to only increase the spacing between bullet points.

Comment: Moreover, I'm sorry for my imprecise jargon. I really started reading about this topic a couple of days ago.